# hadoop-yarn - NodeManager fail to start due to spark_shuffle

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, ambari

I am install hadoop yarn in my cluster. But one of my slave machine fail to start NodeManager due to Service spark_shuffle failed in state INITED.

I try to delete all /tmp/* that related to hadoop, reformat hdfs. But nothing works, I have no clue now

Could you please help me out? Thank you a lot

```
16/06/23 11:31:03 INFO service.AbstractService: Service spark_shuffle failed in state INITED; cause: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:125)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:485)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1089)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:430)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:415)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:903)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:198)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:348)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/06/23 11:31:03 FATAL containermanager.AuxServices: Failed to initialize spark_shuffle
org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceStateException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceStateException.convert(ServiceStateException.java:59)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:172)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices.serviceInit(AuxServices.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:107)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.serviceInit(ContainerManagerImpl.java:245)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:107)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:292)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:547)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:595)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:125)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:485)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1089)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:430)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:415)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:903)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:198)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:348)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/06/23 11:31:03 INFO service.AbstractService: Service org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices failed in state INITED; cause: org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceStateException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceStateException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceStateException.convert(ServiceStateException.java:59)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:172)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices.serviceInit(AuxServices.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:107)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.serviceInit(ContainerManagerImpl.java:245)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:107)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:292)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:547)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:595)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:125)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:485)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1089)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:430)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:415)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:903)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:198)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:348)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/06/23 11:31:03 INFO service.AbstractService: Service org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl failed in state INITED; cause: org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceStateException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceStateException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceStateException.convert(ServiceStateException.java:59)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:172)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices.serviceInit(AuxServices.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:107)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.serviceInit(ContainerManagerImpl.java:245)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:107)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:292)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:547)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:595)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:125)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:485)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1089)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:430)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:415)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:903)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:198)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:348)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/06/23 11:31:03 INFO service.AbstractService: Service NodeManager failed in state INITED; cause: org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceStateException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceStateException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceStateException.convert(ServiceStateException.java:59)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:172)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices.serviceInit(AuxServices.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:107)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.serviceInit(ContainerManagerImpl.java:245)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:107)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:292)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:547)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:595)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:125)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:485)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1089)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:430)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:415)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:903)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:198)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:348)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/06/23 11:31:03 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping NodeManager metrics system...
16/06/23 11:31:03 INFO impl.MetricsSinkAdapter: timeline thread interrupted.
16/06/23 11:31:03 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NodeManager metrics system stopped.
16/06/23 11:31:03 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NodeManager metrics system shutdown complete.
16/06/23 11:31:03 FATAL nodemanager.NodeManager: Error starting NodeManager
org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceStateException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceStateException.convert(ServiceStateException.java:59)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:172)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices.serviceInit(AuxServices.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:107)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl.serviceInit(ContainerManagerImpl.java:245)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:107)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:292)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:547)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:595)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:125)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:485)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1089)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:430)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:415)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:903)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:198)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:348)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/06/23 11:31:03 INFO nodemanager.NodeManager: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NodeManager at grey15/10.1.1.39
************************************************************/
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you may not stopped all the running service, `java.net.BindException: Address already in use` there is still some services running that's why the exception thrown. Tried to stop all the service and you may try again.

Comment: I've tried but cannot figure out what happened. So I decided to re-install everything, and it's ok now. Thank you a lot

Comment: You may check whether the port may used by any other service in your machine. Just find out root cause because it's help you for sometimes.

Comment: Yes, I try to follow the step in this link, but also cannot find out what port is mentioned, even in log files
https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s1-server-ports.html

Comment: I've searched the spark documents, and see some potential ports. But still cannot find it is being used.

Comment: Check your yarn files for the node manger ports configured properly.

Comment: I installed yarn node manager in 7 machines, and only two of them failed to start node manager. So I think the problem is belong to my own machine, it cannot belong to yarn files. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, its may problem with machines. check those machines hadoop logs.

Comment: I am facing the same problem in one of the cdh nodes. I have checked the ports and they are not being used in anyother services

Comment: Late to the conversation but are you running both spark 1 and spark 2? We ran into exactly this problem when we had the spark 2 tech preview installed. Our `yarn-site.xml` contained entries for both `spark_shuffle` and `spark2_shuffle` for `yarn.nodemanager.aux-services`. Removing the `spark2_shuffle` entry fixed the problem for us.